# Помогите, пожалуйста с indexOf java

Tags: java, indexof

есть строка `String targetLine = "aaa2021-03-31:18:10:23";`
надо разделить на `"aaa"` и `"2021-03-31:18:10:23"`
регулярки нельзя, только `indexOf`,
сделать надо примерно так: splittedLine1 = targetLine.substring(0, targetLine.indexOf("2"));` - это будет "ааа"
и splittedLine2 = targetLine.substring(targetLine.indexOf("2"))
это будет "2021-03-31:18:10:23"

но только нужно чтобы `IndexOf` брал не только по двойке, а по любой цифре от 0 до 9
помогите придумать плиз

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перебирайте циклом, как вариант

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String targetLine = "aaa2021-03-31:18:10:23";

    System.out.println(targetLine.substring(targetLine.indexOf(firstDigit(targetLine))));
  }

  public static char firstDigit(String input) {
    int i = 0;
    for (; (int) input.charAt(i) < (int) '0' || (int) input.charAt(i) > (int) '9'; i++)
      ;
    return input.charAt(i);
  }
```

Comment: да, точно, спасибо!